# Removing index.php and another page inside the root folder from URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my Root folder I have `index.php` and `profile.php`.

Currently I'm using these rules for rewrite my `index.php`

from `example.com/index.php?a=profile&u=user1` to `example.com/profile&u=user1`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3     [L]
RewriteRule ^welcome/([^/]+)/?$         index.php?a=welcome             [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$            index.php?a=page&filter=$1      [NC]
```

It works fine but now I want to rewrite my URL for profile.php page too, like this:

from `example.com/profile.php?u=user1` to `example.com/user1`

How can I edit my `.htaccess` to rewrite `profile.php` together?

Comment: Check in the RewriteCond if the requested URL contains "?","&","/","="  symbols and if it does not, then rewrite request to the profile.php.

Comment: @Eugeny it's not clear to me...`index.php` contains those symbols too

Comment: @anubhava Ok, so there is no solution in this case?

Comment: Same URL `/abcd` cannot be handled by both `index.php` and `profile.php`. You must prefix one of it like `/u/abc` for `profile.php`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks, what's the right rewrite rules to transform this `example.com/profile.php?u=user1` into this `example.com/profile/user1` (over my current `.htaccess`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on question and comments above here are the rules that should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^welcome/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?a=welcome&filter=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?a=page&filter=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(([^/]+)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$ index.php?a=$1&q=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I'm really grateful to you :)