# .htaccess URL Rewrite Help Needed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need some help to clean my URL.
I have a PHP script that generate URL's like:

```
http://example.com/index.php?a=profile&u=simon
```

Currently I have an `.htaccess` that clean most of it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^welcome/([^/]+)/?$         index.php?a=welcome&filter=$1   [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^explore/([^/]+)/?$         index.php?a=explore&filter=$1   [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/?$         index.php?a=profile&filter=$1   [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$            index.php?a=page&filter=$1      [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$ index.php?a=$1&q=$3 [L,QSA]
```

The previous link with these rules looks like:

```
http://example.com/profile&u=simon
```

**Is there a way to achieve this?**

```
http://example.com/simon
```

Comment: @anubhava yes, I wish to achieve one of these 2 solutions `/simon` or `/profile/simon` where simon is the variable username

Comment: But you already have a rule to handle `/profile/simon`

Comment: @anubhava Ok thanks, so basically I have something to adjust inside my PHP

Comment: @anubhava I digging it... `/profile/simon` redirects always at profile page of the current user logged in. It redirects also if I type only `/profile`

Comment: It is your last rule that handles `/profile` since everything after `[^/]+` is optional. Not sure why have last rule like that.

Comment: @anubhava it's based on your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36956650/4458531... I have 2 different profile page, one is handled by `index.php` and other one by `profile.php`

Comment: So if `/index.php?a=$1&q=$3` is also a profile URL then what URL is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following, place this at the bottom (bellow your existing rules) :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will internally redirect

- site/foo

to

- site/index.php?a=profile&u=foo

Comment: I tried but it's not working, `http://example.com/foo` redirect always to `/welcome`

Comment: @Simone it's strange!